# Page response time in foreign countries

Tags: time

We are currently preparing to deploy our software in an non EU country. Any hints, how I can check response times from any country? Just to get a feeling when we have to use CDS and stuff...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You absolutely want to test with [WebPageTest.org](http://www.webpagetest.org/)** It's a free service by Patrick Meenan and others. Essentially it consists of dedicated Internet Explorer instances, hosted around the world, which will load your page and show you:

- Waterfall charts of the resources loaded, and load times etc.
- Caching headers scores, image compression scores, and other scores for best practice page load optimizations.
- A little sequence of screenshots showing how the site renders.

With [Webpagetest.org](http://www.webpagetest.org/) you cannot test from any country, 'just' from the 20 or so locations they currently support.

In addition to Webpagetest's one-off testing, you can also set up ongoing testing using fx [Gomez](http://www.gomez.com), [Pingdom](http://www.pingdom.com), or any of the many other website testing services.

If you want to know more about this field, then the [book "High Performance Web Sites" by Steve Souders](http://stevesouders.com/) is the best starting point.

Comment: I will have a Look, but Sounds just like what i Need :) thanks